# Emscripten seems to not use asm.js

Tags: javascript, emscripten, asm.js

I've read in emscripten docs that emscripten compiles to asm.js optimisations by default, but if I open compiled code I can't find any "use asm;" how to get it? Should I add it manually or am I compiling wrong?

At the moment I am using  "emcc main.c -o out.html" to compile, also tried with -02 flag.

Comment: Do you know, that "use asm;" does not do anyghing, so you can omit it?

Comment: I've seen library like [this](https://github.com/tonyg/js-scrypt/blob/master/browser/scrypt.js) that when used print in the js console asm.js compiled, and in fact they seem pretty fast. Code that i have compiled don't have any use asm and in fact they are not compiled. :/

Comment: `emcc -O2` should emit asm.js code. Are you on latest emscripten? Do you see any errors in the commandline?

Comment: @IvanKuckir It does make a difference, at least in recent Firefox versions: http://techcrunch.com/2013/12/21/mozillas-asm-js-gets-another-step-closer-to-native-performance/

Answer (score 4):

This is by design. Sometimes it generates (see the [source code](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/b3efd9328f940034e1cab45af23bf29541e0d8ff/emscripten.py#L694)) `"almost asm"` instead of `"use asm"`, which disables all asm.js optimizations. This happens when compiled code uses some features (like [this v8 issue](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3907)) that are not implemented in browsers.
For the project I'm working on now, I have replaced `"almost asm"` with `"use asm"` for Firefox and left it as is for Chrome because `"use asm"` caused heavy slowdown at start.

So, it's not safe to just replace `"almost asm"` with `"use asm"` but sometimes this works ok. You should carefully test your app in all browser versions (but make sure you are testing with devtools turned off) you have to support - and if it works, this means that you have a lucky case that is already implemented: go ahead and replace.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution, but I replaced the "almost asm" with "use asm" and it worked with Firefox (was correctly compiled and measurable faster).

I also searched long for a solution to get Emscripten to do that itself, but didn't found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

asm.js was used when the fastcomp backend was in place. So you need to revert back to that by building it from source. You can try to use 1.38.48 or whatever the last version that supports the fastcomp backend from the emsdk list repository, but I have found this method more reliable.

[Building Fastcomp](https://docs.huihoo.com/emscripten/emscripten-site/docs/building_from_source/building_fastcomp_manually_from_source.html)

To build the Fastcomp code from source:

- Create a directory to store the build. It doesn’t matter where, because Emscripten gets the information from the compiler configuration file (~/.emscripten). We show how to update this file later in these instructions:

  ```
  mkdir myfastcomp
  cd myfastcomp
  ```
- Clone the fastcomp LLVM repository (https://github.com/kripken/emscripten-fastcomp):

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/kripken/emscripten-fastcomp
  ```
- Clone the kripken/emscripten-fastcomp-clang repository into emscripten-fastcomp/tools/clang:

  ```
  cd emscripten-fastcomp
  git clone https://github.com/kripken/emscripten-fastcomp-clang tools/clang
  ```

> You must clone it into a directory named clang as shown, so that Clang is present in tools/clang!

- Create a build directory (inside the emscripten-fastcomp directory) and then navigate into it:

  ```
  mkdir build
  cd build
  ```
- Configure the build using either cmake or the configure script:
- Using cmake:

  ```
  cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86;JSBackend" -DLLVM_INCLUDE_EXAMPLES=OFF -DLLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS=OFF -DCLANG_INCLUDE_EXAMPLES=OFF -DCLANG_INCLUDE_TESTS=OFF
  ```

> On Windows add the -G "Visual Studio 10 Win64" directive to build using Visual Studio (Visual Studio 2011 and 2012 do NOT work).

- Using configure (Linux/Mac only):

  ```
  ../configure --enable-optimized --disable-assertions --enable-targets=host,js
  ```
- Determine the number of available cores on your system (Emscripten can run many operations in parallel, so using more cores may have a significant impact on compilation time):

> On Mac OS X you can get the number of cores using: Apple menu | About this mac | More info | System report. The Hardware overview on the resulting dialog includes a Total number of cores entry.

> On Linux you can find the number of cores by entering the following command on the terminal: cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "^cpu cores" | uniq.

> On Windows the number of cores is listed on the Task Manager | Performance Tab. You can open the Task Manager by entering Ctrl + Shift + Esc from the Desktop.

- Call make to build the sources, specifying the number of available cores:

  ```
  make -j4
  ```

> If the build completes successfully, clang, clang++, and a number of other files will be created in the release directory (/build/Release/bin).

- The final step is to update the ~/.emscripten file, specifying the location of fastcomp in the LLVM_ROOT variable.

  Note

> If you’re building the whole of Emscripten from source, following the platform-specific instructions in Building Emscripten from Source, you won’t yet have Emscripten installed. In this case, skip this step and return to those instructions.

If you already have an Emscripten environment (for example if you’re building Fastcomp using the SDK), then set LLVM_ROOT to the location of the clang binary under the build directory. This will be something like /build/Release/bin or /build/bin:

```
LLVM_ROOT='/home/ubuntu/yourpath/emscripten-fastcomp/build/bin'
```